# Nginx,PHP-FPM,PHP Module and MySQL Implementation is possible in Kubernetes

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes. I have setup kubernetes with 1 master and 3 slave nodes. I have created mysql and nginx pods and it is running on different nodes successfully. Now I want to deploy my application. It has nginx,php-fpm, PHPmodule and MySQL combination. How can I achieve this in Kubernetes?

Here is what I have tried for php-fpm,

cat php-fpm.yaml :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: php-fpm
  labels:
    name: php-fpm
spec:
  containers:
    - resources:
        limits :
          cpu: 0.5
      image: php-fpm
      name: php-fpm
      env:
        - name: PHPFPM_SERVICE
          # change this

      ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
          name: php-fpm
```

cat php-fpm-service.yaml :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: php-fpm
  name: php-fpm
spec:
  externalIPs:
    - 10.128.0.3
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
    - port: 9000
  # label keys and values that must match in order to receive traffic for this service
  selector:
    name: php-fpm
```

But php-fpm Pod is not running; the output is below.

```
NAME      READY     STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
mysql     1/1       Running        0          1d
mysql1    1/1       Running        0          18h
nginx     1/1       Running        0          18h
php-fpm   0/1       ErrImagePull   0          1m
```

How can I get it running?

Comment: Show your definitions, ask about specific problems and tell us what you tried before. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Janos, I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your Pod fails to start because it can't find the image you specified on docker hub (`ErrImagePull`).

Change `php-fpm.yaml` like this:

```
...
image: php:fpm
...
```

See the full list of [official php image tags](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/).

To get a better overall idea I suggest read the [tutorial on running WordPress on kubernetes (using mysql)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/mysql-wordpress-pd/README.md) before you try to roll your own solution.

Comment: Thanks Janos, after changed the image name its worked fine.Now how can I use php for nginx-php-fpm and how can I communicate between them with MySQL server.Could you please share some links.

Comment: Look at the tutorial I've linked.

Comment: Thanks Janos.I will check the given links.

Comment: I have tried with volume attachment by followed below link for nginx webserver, https://deis.com/blog/2016/kubernetes-overview-pt-2/  Pods and services created successfully but when i tried in nginx webserver browser it is not reachable. More Details : http://tinypic.com/r/2j5106r/9 , http://tinypic.com/r/9sfi3k/9 , http://tinypic.com/r/14ifo1g/9